# Change value of rows in a column that match condition with values from a list or a Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select rows based on two conditions

```
df.Length.str.isnumeric() == False & df.Type == "Type1"
```

and change the values of all corresponding rows, in a specific column `Length`, to a value from a list, such as:

```
[120, 2151, 215, 25, 2451]
```

Thank you!

Comment: please show an example of your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: How do you want to select the value from the list?

Comment: Let's say I have a df with two columns "Length" and "Type", and all the NaN values in Length i want to change to a value from a precomputed list.

Comment: Are you randomly selecting the values from that list?

Comment: Nope, it is sorted to match the order of the indices of the values in the dataframe.

Comment: `lst = np.array([120, 2151, 215, 25, 2451]).reshape(-1,1); df.loc[df['Length'].isna() & (df.Type == "Type1"), 'Length'] = lst[df['Length'].isna() & (df.Type == "Type1")]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

Following your comment, I came up with this shorter solution.

```
import pandas as pd
import math

df = pd.DataFrame(
                [
                [10, 15, float('NaN')],
                [25, 30, 35],
                [40, 45, 50],
                [55, 60, float('NaN')]
                ], columns=list('ABC'))

pre_computed_list = [20, 65]


row_indices = df['C'][df['C'].apply(math.isnan)].index.tolist()
df['C'][row_indices] = pre_computed_list
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe it would work. I would just prefer a solution that was more like:
df['C'][row_indices] = pre_computed_list